# Program with Infinite loop stops executing by itself

Tags: infinite-loop

The following program  is trying to flood myself by sending tcp packets to my IP. The problem is that it stops executing after about a minute. 
What could be the cause of that?

Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>    //strlen
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> //inet_addr

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
int socket_desc;
struct sockaddr_in server;
char *message;

//Create socket
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if (socket_desc == -1)
{
    printf("Could not create socket");
}

server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("129.0.0.1");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 80 );

//Connect to remote server
if (connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) < 0)
{
    puts("connect error");
    return 1;
}

puts("Connected\n");

//Send some data
message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
while(1)
{
if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
{
    puts("Send failed");

}
puts("Packet Send\n");
 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the return status?

Comment: What do you mean with 'stops executing': it is still running but not printing, or has it terminated?

Comment: @Kenney I am running it on a ubuntu terminal and it is terminated ,with the last printed statement being "Packet Send" (as were all the previous since it entered the while loop).